# What is the difference between <header> and <h1> in html

Tags: html, header, head, html-heading

What is the difference between  and  in html, I've been recently learning it and someone asked me this question and I'm unable to conclude the perfect answer for it

h1 and header can both perform the same tasks hence what's the diff?

Comment: Read about semantic tags here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics#semantics_in_html

Comment: ya that helped made a little more sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<h1>` is used to define the main heading of a page, while `<header>` is used to define a container for introductory content or navigational links. They have different purposes and cannot be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

`<h1>` is used for indicating the main title of a web page or section, while `<header>` is a section of the page that contains various elements including the main title, logo, and navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

`<h1>` is use for headings. it's part of the H Tags like h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 and h5. This will create a heading hierarchy that helps Google and the other search engines understand the structure of your text on the page.

The `<header>` tag is used to define a container for introductory content or a set of navigational links. Which can include a logo or site title, and sometimes the main navigation menu.